# Import CSV with Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, roo

I have 2 models `Order has_many line_items` and `line_item belongs_to order`. The order has been created and the file import form is on the order show form. i am using roo gem for CSV import, but I do not have to if there is another solution. Each row in the spreadsheet is a new line_item but I need to save the order_id for each line. I'm open to all solutions.

orders/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag import_line_items_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

line_items_controller.rb

```
  def import
    LineItem.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Products imported."
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params, :order_id => :order_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'csv'
    belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :line_items

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      line_item = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
      line_item.attributes = row.to_hash
      line_item.order_id = @order
      puts @order
      line_item.save!
    end
  end  
end
```

This is the error I'm getting with this code...

```
Validation failed: Order must exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the `order` to `import` action and `self.import` methods. For example:

**orders/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag import_line_items_path, multipart: true do %>
  # Send order_id via hidden_field_tag
  <%= hidden_field_tag :order_id, params[:id] %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

**line_items_controller.rb**

```
def import
  order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  LineItem.import(params[:file], order)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

**line_item.rb**

```
def self.import(file, order)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    line_item = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
    line_item.attributes = row.to_hash
    line_item.order_id = order.id
    puts order
    line_item.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Code looks like what I am trying to accomplish and I think I had some kind of version like that at one time, but I'm getting an error... 'Couldn't find Order without an ID' for 'order = Order.find(params[:order_id])' in the line_items_controller.rb

Comment: Could you check the `params` received when calling import?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GX1OtMmvKKqo29wmtmmruP0d6NrxloEyXJxczv9oXibQyJn4cIZ+N1ieef5ihrGNoqHSYInov3Q22tsyzd3F5Q==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb73135af08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/8r/z1fs_pxj3213cvv2jt2cc5t40000gn/T/RackMultipart20181008-1138-szqrd7.csv>, @original_filename="UTL MENIFEE - FALL - 2018 - 1003308 (2).csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"UTL MENIFEE - FALL - 2018 - 1003308 (2).csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">, "commit"=>"Import"}

Comment: @DhatchXIX That's strange, it should have the `order_id` params. Did you put the `hidden_field_tag`?

Comment: It would help if i saved the show page file. Thanks for the help!